# Why is this background not being tiled correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, reveal.js

I modified the reveal.js parallax background so it is resized to tile once per PDF export page. However, depending on the reveal.js [presentation size](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#presentation-size), the tiling gets messed up. Sometimes the tile height is slightly too large, and this error keeps accumulating.

**Questions:**

- What causes the tiling to get messed up?
- Which presentation sizes will not get messed up? (960x678 works, but not 960x700)
- How to modify reveal.js so all presentation sizes are tiled correctly?

**You can try it out here:**

- Open the links below in Chrome and open print dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>)

  - [Badly tiled](https://cyan-shirt.hyperdev.space/?print-pdf)
  - [Tiles OK](https://cyan-shirt.hyperdev.space/tiles-ok.html?print-pdf)
- View [source code](https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/cyan-shirt) (relevant code is at bottom of index.html)

**Here is a screen shot of the messed up tiling:**

[image]

---

**Finally, here is how I modified reveal.js:**

I changed this line:

```
dom.background.style.backgroundSize = config.parallaxBackgroundSize;
```

to this:

```
if ( isPrintingPDF() ) {
    var slideSize = getComputedSlideSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    // Dimensions of the PDF pages; copied from another part of reveal.js
    var pageWidth = Math.floor( slideSize.width * ( 1 + config.margin ) ),
        pageHeight = Math.floor( slideSize.height * ( 1 + config.margin  ) );

    dom.background.style.backgroundSize = pageWidth + 'px ' + pageHeight + 'px';
} else {
    dom.background.style.backgroundSize = config.parallaxBackgroundSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the reveal.js this change the size of the page:

```
        // Let the browser know what page size we want to print
        injectStyleSheet( '@page{size:'+ pageWidth +'px '+ pageHeight +'px; margin: 0;}' );

        // Limit the size of certain elements to the dimensions of the slide
        injectStyleSheet( '.reveal section>img, .reveal section>video, .reveal section>iframe{max-width: '+ slideWidth +'px; max-height:'+ slideHeight +'px}' );
```

Comment: I copied the calculations for `pageWidth` and `pageHeight` from that part of reveal.js. So the background tile size and page size *should* match. (And AFAIK they do match, based on inspection via the browser debug tools...)

Comment: check the position absulute and relative this can breake your design